# $(document).on('click', '.class-name') firing multiple

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a list of items ..each row has a delete button that when triggered will delete a document from the database...each delete button is bound to a click event and calls an Ajax method on the server-side.  When the Ajax success: event is triggered I want to remove the entire row $(".parent-row") from the list and show a notification message...

What is happening is that the button-click event fires for the correct button/row and calls the Server-side delete and I'm able to remove the row from the DOM....BUT if I delete a second document immediately after then...not only does the button-click event for the document I WANT to delete fire...the button-click event from the PREVIOUS button-click event fires as well ...so I have 2 events firing...one completes successfully...one fails...If I delete a 3rd document...then I get 2 fails and 1 success...and do so on....

I'm just wondering why/how the events are still firing even after the elements have been removed from the DOM....and how to fix that.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-thin parent-row">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h6 class="pull-left">somefilename.pdf</h6>
        <div class="btn btn-danger pull-right confirm-del-document" data-ref-id="999" data-filename="somefilename.pdf"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED JAVASCRIPT:**
I've attached the entire onclick event:

```
$(document).on(".confirm-del-document","click", function (e) {
    var refID = $(this).data("ref-id");
    var docName = $(this).data("filename");
    var parentRow = $(this).closest(".parent-row");
    var sourceButton = $(this);

    ConfirmMessage("Delete Service Run Document", "You are going to delete:<br/><small class='text-danger'>'" + docName + "' from this Service Run'.</small>", "Do you want to continue?", function (response) {
        if(response == true) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ServiceRun/RemoveDocument',
                    type: 'POST',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: {
                        xRefId: refID
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.Success) {
                            $(sourceButton).removeClass("confirm-del-document"); //remove the click event from this button before removing it from the DOM
                            $(parentRow).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                                $(this).remove();
                                ShowMessage(data.Message, 'success');
                            }); //remove the row ...slowly....                                                                                                         
                        }
                        else {
                            ShowMessage(data.ErrorMessage, 'danger');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, status, message) {
                        ShowMessage(message, 'danger');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });         
});
```

**UPDATE**
I'm using Bootstrap notify for my notifications...

ShowMessage Code:

```
function ShowMessage(notificationMessage, type) {
    //notify
    $.notify({
        message: notificationMessage
        },
        {
            // settings
            type: type,
            placement: {
            from: "bottom",
            align: "right"
        },
        animate: {
            enter: 'animated fadeInUp',
            exit: 'animated fadeOutDown'
        },
        z_index: 10000,
    });
}
```

I've actually left out a bit of code...the Ajax call I've included is only being called if the user clicks on the "YES" button of a modal window..this is how I'm showing the window:

```
<div id="confirmWindow" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="confirmTitle"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h5 id="confirmMessage"></h5>
                <h6><em id="confirmPrompt">Do you want to continue?</em></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnYes">YES</div>
                <div class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnNo">NO</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the function to manage the Confirm Window

```
//Code to display Modal ConfirmWindow
function ConfirmMessage(title, message, prompt, callback) {
    message = message || '';
    $('#confirmTitle').html(title);
    $('#confirmMessage').html(message);

    if (prompt)
        $('#confirmPrompt').html(prompt);

    $('#confirmWindow').modal({ show: true });

    $('#btnYes').click(function (e) {
        // user confirmed 'Yes'
        $('#confirmWindow').modal('hide');
        if (callback) callback(true);
    });

    $('#btnNo').click(function (e) {
        //  user confirmed 'No'
        $('#confirmWindow').modal('hide');
        if (callback) callback(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is attaching the callbacks as well as the code for `ShowMessage`? It looks like you are attaching the callback for every button each time you delete. If that ajax is executed in a click handler, the `.off('click')` shouldn't do anything because it only effects that row and you removing immediately after.

Comment: And a little bit of helpful advice: I think you want to put the `.remove` inside the "complete" callback of `.fadeOut` because I think in your code it will remove immediately before it gets a chance to fade it out.

Comment: That is definitely an "index" issue. **Show more code**. You probably use `.eq()` based on something I can't figure. So, show the click handler.

Comment: As an aside, why are you using a div as a "button"? This is an accessibility fail, because keyboard-only users can't use the page. You should use an actual button, or a link (styled as you see fit). Also, `async: false`? Just don't.

Comment: thanks @KodosJohnson for the tip fadeOut/remove advice...makes sense and works as expected....

Comment: @nnnnnn ...thanks for the note on keyboard accessibility...not actually an issue as  the users are heavily mouse-oriented but good to identify that for future cases...also I've removed the async: false  ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit, I see what your problem is now. Each time you click on `.confirm-del-document`, you call `ConfirmMessage`, which, in turn, attaches another click handler to the `#btnYes` and `#btnNo` buttons. Event handlers can be stacked so every time you call `ConfirmMessage`, you are adding another handler. You can solve this by replacing `$('#btnYes').click(function(){})` with `$('#btnYes').one('click', function(){})`.    And do the same for the `#btnNo` button.

`.one()` is a jquery function that attaches the event for a specific type ("click" in this case) no more than one time.

More about `.one()` here: http://api.jquery.com/one/

---

Another solution is to remove the callback argument that is doing the ajax call from the `ConfirmMessage` function. And just attach them outside of the `ConfirmMessage` function. Like this:

```
//Code to display Modal ConfirmWindow
function ConfirmMessage(title, message, prompt, callback) {
    message = message || '';
    $('#confirmTitle').html(title);
    $('#confirmMessage').html(message);

    if (prompt)
        $('#confirmPrompt').html(prompt);

    $('#confirmWindow').modal({ show: true });

} 

$('#btnYes').click(function (e) {
    // user confirmed 'Yes'
    $('#confirmWindow').modal('hide');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ServiceRun/RemoveDocument',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {
            xRefId: refID
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success) {
                $(sourceButton).removeClass("confirm-del-document"); //remove the click event from this button before removing it from the DOM
                $(parentRow).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                    ShowMessage(data.Message, 'success');
                }); //remove the row ...slowly....                                                                                                         
            }
            else {
                ShowMessage(data.ErrorMessage, 'danger');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, message) {
            ShowMessage(message, 'danger');
        }
    });
});

$('#btnNo').click(function (e) {
    //  user confirmed 'No'
    $('#confirmWindow').modal('hide');

    // Don't need to make the ajax here
});
```

Comment: *ACCEPTED*
.one("click")..... WORKED....thanks very much @Kodos Johnson!  Because I re-use that snippet of confirmation code in other places in my app (where I was seeing similar behaviour)... by adding the .one("click") event to that specific button right in the ConfirmationMessage function, means I don't have to adjust any existing code and multiple events are no longer firing!

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code can go something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fa-trash').click(function() {
    //alert($(this).attr('class'));
    var parent_row = $(this).parents('.parent-row');
    console.log(parent_row);
    $(parent_row).fadeOut();
    //$(parent_row).remove();//if you want to remove the row, uncomment this line
  });
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is really outdated; use `$(function() { })`.

Comment: @Soviut, where can I read the docs about `$(document).ready()` being outdated? Thanks

Comment: @VandolphReyes on the jQuery website. https://api.jquery.com/ready/  `As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated. This is because the selection has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method`